# iOS7: How to fix "Chrome data compression proxy" error?

Tags: php, iphone, google-chrome, mobile, symfony-1.4

I have a simple web page with a form that gets submitted via normal form, running on local machine with MAMP, and accessing via local Wi-Fi networks.

The form works fine when submitting it on a desktop browser and Safari on iPhone, but the form gets an error when submitted using Chrome on iPhone.

I get the following error message:

> This page cannot be loaded via the "chrome data compression proxy. Try reloading this page.

I have no idea how to fix this issue despite searching around.

The web site or environment following:

[ Web site ]

- iMac 10.9.2 (Mavericks)
- Running with MAMP (Apache with APC+PHP+MySQL)
- Using PHP framework "symfony 1.4.x"

[ Test device ]

- iPhone iOS7
- Safari on iPhone
- Chrome on iPhone
- Accessing via local Wi-Fi networks

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thanks,
Takuya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the tech lead for the Chrome compression proxy. This error is sent when you try to access a URL through the proxy which we cannot access for some reason; e.g., it's behind a local network. Normally for GET requests the browser should automatically retry the request without the proxy, but when using POST this is not possible. Are you using POST with a local (non-public) web address for this request?

If you can provide some further details I'll see if I can help. Sorry for the trouble.